# Как получить id вызывающего компонента в управляемом бине

Tags: java, mvc, java-ee, xhtml, jsf

Как в управляемом бине (managed bean) получить `id` компонента, который вызвал `action` метод на данном управляемом бине?

Иными словами, как получить id компонента `<h:commandLink>` или `<h:commandButton>` в действии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Информацию о командном элементе, вызвавшем действие, можно получить в передаваемом событии [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/ActionEvent.html) слушателя действия (`actionListener`), но не в самом действии (`action`):

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.actionListener}" ... />
```

с

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent event) {
    String componentId = event.getComponent().getClientId();
    //...
}
```

Можно также получить информацию об `id` вызвавшего событие элемента и следующими альтернативными способами:

1. Передавая `id` элемента в событии в качестве дополнительного параметра при условии EL2.2+. Для этого будет использован неявный EL-объект `component`:

   ```
   <h:commandButton action="#{bean.action(component.clientId)}" ... />
   ```

   с

   ```
   public String action(String id) {
       //...
   }
   ```
2. Путем регистрации дополнительного тэга командного элемента ...

   - и использования `<f:param>`:

     ```
     <h:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" ... >
         <f:param name="id" value="#{component.clientId}" />
     </h:commandButton>
     ```

     с

     ```
     public String action() {
         String id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext.getRequestParametesp.get("id");
     }
     ```

     или с

     ```
     @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
     private String id;//+setter
     ```
   - и использования `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`:

     ```
     <h:commandButton ... >
         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.id}" value="#{component.clientId}" />
     </h:commandButton>
     ```

     с

     ```
     private String id;//+setter
     ```

### Дополнительная информация:

- [Difference between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener);
- [Communication in JSF 2.0, section on *Implicit objects*](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects);
- [How can I pass a parameter to a commandLink inside a dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable).